# Autocomplete not working in fancybox

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, fancybox

Im having a problem with including a autocomplete jquery text box within a jquery fancybox.
The autocomplete textbox seems to work fine if it is out of the fancybox but as soon as I use it within the fancybox it doesnt work at all...Almost like you cant use jquery within jquery?

Code is as follows (Links to jquery files have already been made):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="site/themes/ama/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="site/themes/ama/fancyBox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="site/themes/ama/fancyBox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />


<script>
var availableTags = ["one","two","three"];
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableTags
  });
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

> The fancybox div is below

```
<div id="display" style="display:none;">
<form name="upload" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
```

> This is the textbox that isnt working as a autocomplete textbox.

```
<input type="text" id="tags" name="gallery" style="height: 20px;">
</form>
</div>

<p style="clear:both;"><a href="#display" class="fancybox">Upload Images</a></p>
```

Thanx for any help!

**UPDATE**
I've tried using noConflict but have come to the realization that it is only for conflicts between jquery framework and other frameworks not with plugins made for jquery. I am seriously so confused with this issue...

Comment: Did you check your javascript console for any errors/warnings? and what is test1, test2, test3, are they actual variables? played a bit with your code, it works if you have items in your array http://jsfiddle.net/amaroks/uBK3U/

Comment: yes I have checked the error console and no errors were found. test1, test2, test3 are just test elements within the array. I can get the autocomplete working fine, the problem comes in when implementing it within the fancybox.

Comment: what version of fancybox?

Comment: does the autocomplete actually work in the fancybox but just not show? or not work at all?

Comment: Thanx for the reply john. It doesn't work at all in the fancybox but it will work out of the fancybox.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your CSS, that will solve the issue:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 99999;
}
```